# assigning jQuery functions considered harmful?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function-pointers

This code was working fine:

```
if (chk.checked)
    div.show(delay);
else
    div.hide(delay);
```

I tried to be clever by refactoring it like this:

```
var showHide = chk.checked ? div.show : div.hide;
showHide(delay);
```

but that caused an exception inside jQuery.  Shouldn't the 2 pieces of code be equivalent?

Comment: What was the exception that was thrown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this instead:

```
var showHide = chk.checked ? 'show' : 'hide';
div[showHide](delay);
```

If you just save a reference to the function, you'll lose the receiver — that is, inside the function the `this` reference will be wrong.

I guess you could do this instead:

```
var showHide = chk.checked ? div.show : div.hide;
showHide.call(div, delay);
```

*edit* or, to avoid referring to "div" twice in the first line:

```
var showHide = div[chk.checked ? 'show' : 'hide'];
```

I'm not sure such a refactoring makes anything clearer :-)

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this solution is it repeats references to "div"

Comment: @JoelFan OK I can fix that :-)

Comment: I like this better because it doesn't reference 'div' at all: var showHide = chk.checked ? $.fn.show : $.fn.hide;

Comment: @JoelFan well sure but then it references `$.fn` twice in exchange. If `div` is a local variable, references to it would be (trivially) cheaper.

Comment: I still prefer referencing $.fn because it's more general... you are not really gaining anything specific from "div" by referencing it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `show` and `hide` functions are not properties of that particular jQuery selection object. They are properties of the jQuery prototype object.

So this, for instance, returns true:

```
$('div').show === $.fn.show;
```

There is only one `show` function, and doing `var showHide = div.show` only assigns the generic function to the variable. Crucially, it does not import the *context*, which is what calling it with `div.show()` does.

The simple way is to use the property name as a variable, rather than the function itself, as [Pointy's answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12729624/417562), or to use `call`, as he also suggests. The other alternative is to use `bind` (or `$.proxy` if you have to support older browsers):

```
var showHide = (chk.checked ? div.show : div.hide).bind(div);
showHide(delay);
```

I'm really not sure this is worth the effort, however...

Comment: I found that you can also do: var showHide = (chk.checked ? $.fn.show : $.fn.hide).bind(div);  This avoids unnecessary references to "div"

Comment: This is a bit clearer than using "bind" and also works: var showHide = chk.checked ? $.fn.show : $.fn.hide; showHide.call(div, delay);

Comment: @JoelFan You can do that, if you prefer. I would still recommend Pointy's solution, though. Or, of course, [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for this particular instance.

Comment: How could I use "toggle"?  I need to show or hide based on if the checkbox is checked or not

Comment: @JoelFan Sorry, my mistake. You can use `toggle(chk.checked)` (will show if `chk.checked` is true, hide otherwise), but it's not possible to do a delay as well. (Unless, of course, you programmed an extension to `toggle` yourself, which would be trivially easy.)